# PullToRefreshListView onTouch event and onclick events is not working for parent activity

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I have implemented PullToRefersh list view using fragments using single activity but `pulltorefresh` is working in  parent activity, `ontouch` is not working i have used [Android-PullToRefresh library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)

how can I fix it?

Activity layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_background" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/event_list_view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/gray_color"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Give here you code snippet...

Comment: i have two fragments one is list view and frame layout, list view having no.of items here i have applied pull to refresh animation but when i go to frame layout here two button is there but when i click is not wotking event touch alos not wotking.....

Comment: Are both fragment in single layout? Are both fragment have same layout_width,height ?

Comment: I use this in one of my project, 5 fragment, not get this issue...

Comment: i have used android navigation drawer with 7 fragments one of the fragments having listview here i have applied this animation , and have u used same library.........?

Comment: listView and FrameView placed are in one layout?

Comment: but why is working for me , just i have applied that pull to refresh alone , can u help me how to fix it, thanks for responding..

Comment: yes in activity i have used list view and frame layout according android navigation drawer selection am showing fragments ....

Comment: can you me layout code of navigation drawer, fragments (listview & FrameLayout)?

Comment: check it now i have update my question

Comment: I test it and it is working as it should be

Comment: download from https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zwr5sd7cz6r6sm/Help.zip